# Server Client in Java only displays message when I press enter

Tags: java

I have this server and client code. If i send a message from my server to my client it wont display unless I send a message to my client back first or I press enter, the same problem occurs when I try the other way around. How can I fix this?

**Server:**

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket sersock = new ServerSocket(3000);
        System.out.println("Server ready for chatting");
        Socket sock = sersock.accept(); // reading from keyboard (keyRead object) 
        BufferedReader keyRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); // sending to client (pwrite object)
        OutputStream ostream = sock.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter pwrite = new PrintWriter(ostream, true);   // receiving from server ( receiveRead object) 
        InputStream istream = sock.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader receiveRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream));
        String receiveMessage, sendMessage;

        GossipServer gs = new GossipServer();
        gs.initalisePieces();
        gs.displayBoard(pwrite);

        pwrite.println("Welcome to my Chess Game - Designed by Robbie Singh");
        while (true) {
            if ((receiveMessage = receiveRead.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(receiveMessage);
            }
            sendMessage = keyRead.readLine();
            pwrite.println(sendMessage);
            pwrite.flush();
        }
    }
```

**Client:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 3000); // reading from keyboard (keyRead object) 
        BufferedReader keyRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); // sending to client (pwrite object)
        OutputStream ostream = sock.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter pwrite = new PrintWriter(ostream, true);   // receiving from server ( receiveRead object) 
        InputStream istream = sock.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader receiveRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream));
        System.out.println("Welcome to my Chess Game - Designed by Robbie Singh");
        String receiveMessage, sendMessage;
        while (true) {
            sendMessage = keyRead.readLine(); // keyboard reading 
            pwrite.println(sendMessage); // sending to server 
            pwrite.flush(); // flush the data 
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
                    System.out.println(receiveRead.readLine());
                    }catch(Exception e){}
                }
            }, 0, 5000);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That's way in the server side you are waiting for a keyboard input in the main loop.

```
    while (true) 
    {
        if ((receiveMessage = receiveRead.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            System.out.println(receiveMessage);
        }

        //PUT THESE LINE IN OTHER THREAD AND SHOULD FIX THE PROBLEM
        sendMessage = keyRead.readLine();
        pwrite.println(sendMessage);
        pwrite.flush();
        //////////////////////////////////////////
    }
```

By the way i do suggest you to read the chat application example in this links: http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/