# Java server/client application only displays messages upon pressing enter

Tags: java, sockets, networking, port, serversocket

Server Side:

```
try {
    ServerSocket server_socket=new ServerSocket(port_number);
    Socket client_socket= server_socket.accept();
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(client_socket.getOutputStream(),true);
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client_socket.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader stdIn=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String userInput, clientOutput;
    while ((userInput=stdIn.readLine())!="EXIT") {
        if ((clientOutput=input.readLine())!=null) {
            System.out.println("Client: "+clientOutput);
        } if (userInput!=null) {
            output.println(userInput);
            output.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Client Side:

```
try {
    Socket client_socket= new Socket(hostname,port_number);
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(client_socket.getOutputStream(),true);
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client_socket.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader stdIn=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String userInput,serverOutput;
    while ((userInput=stdIn.readLine())!="EXIT") {
        if ((serverOutput=input.readLine())!=null) {
            System.out.println("Server: "+serverOutput);
        } if (userInput!=null) {
            output.println(userInput);
            output.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

The code in my case makes sense to me, I cant seem to figure out why an enter still needs to be pressed, does it have something to do with `.readLine()`?
I checked out the following post [Server Client in Java only displays message when I press enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31213063/server-client-in-java-only-displays-message-when-i-press-enter), however the solution provided does not fix the situation.

Note: Initially there were no if statements in the while loop. The way I saw this to be an issue was that the while loop may get stuck on one of the lines, waiting for user/server input. Therefore implementing if statements allowed it to skip the waiting portion and re-run the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I mixed my variables up. 
The while loops should be:

```
 while ((userInput=input.readLine())!="EXIT") {
```

It fixed it, but there are some other issues still present

Answer (score 0):

> does it have something to do with .getLine()?

Yes. If you look at the [Javadoc for BufferedReader#readLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()), it clearly states that an end of line character terminates the String to be read:

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

Comment: So I appended `\n` to the `userInput` that are sent, and it still dd not fix the issue.